Definition of circle, line, tangent in Euclidean plane without coordinates
I am trying to understand objects in Euclidean space without using coordinates (i.e. expressing its elements as $n$-tuples of real numbers).
For simplicity I am considering Euclidean plane.
I then asked myself, - what is circle, straight line, tangent line to a circle in Euclidean plane?
Since I am habituated of thinking Euclidean plane as $\mathbb{R}^2$ and describing above objects in terms of ordered pairs, I could not think of defining the mentioned objects without coordinates, and I stuck at how we define these objects without coordinates?
Can one suggest some way to think of these objects without coordinates? (Specifically, I want to understand definition of circle and tangent line to it).

You can take an axiomatic approach to developing Euclidean geometry. Might be worth finding a book that does that, or perhaps looking into Hilbert’s axioms for Euclidean geometry.

If you don't have coordinates then you need to have something else; there are various choices for what that something else is to start with, some of which are literally thousands of years old. For example if you still have distances then a circle consists of all points at a fixed distance from a fixed point, and a line consists of all points at the same distance from two distinct points.

@Luc, you have to define "line" before you can use it to define "tangent".

If $A$ and $B$ are distinct points, ${x|Distance(x,A)=Distance(x,B)}$ is a line and ${x|Distance(x,A)=Distance(A,B)}$ is a circle. A line and circle are tangent iff their intersection contains exactly 1 point.

You can’t do anything with something unless you know what it is. Do you have a definition of Euclidean space you want to use?

Here's a possible approach: https://math.berkeley.edu/~wodzicki/160/Hilbert.pdf

As for the tangent, a simple definition is the following: a line is tangent to a circle if it has a single point in common with it.

I believe that a straight line cannot be defined in terms of more primitive geometric concepts; that's why axiomatic geometric systems, like Hilbert's, present it as a primitive concept.

A euclidean plane may be defined as a real vector space $V$ of dimension $2$, with a dot product $$\langle.,.\rangle:V\times V\to \mathbb R$$ $$(u,v)\mapsto \langle u,v\rangle$$ie a bilinear  form defined and positive. We will note also simply $u\cdot v$ instead of $\langle u,v\rangle$.

A line is defined in any vector space $W$, not only of dimension $2$, by a part $l$ of $W$ of the form $$\boxed{l\doteq a+\mathbb Ru}$$where $a\in W, u\in W$;
Since you are habituated of thinking Euclidean plane as $\mathbb R^2$
and describing above objects in terms of ordered pairs, you can think about $$(3,2)+\mathbb R(1,4)$$for example. (That is the way Serge Lang shows it at the beginning of Linear Algebra 1.)
Let us write $u^2\doteq u\cdot u$(you find these notations with Herman Weyl, Emil Artin(Lang's Master), ...) and $$||u||\doteq \sqrt{u^2}$$Then the circle of center $a$ and radius $r$ is simply defined as $$\boxed{\mathscr C(a,r)\doteq \{x\in V: ||x-a||=r\}}$$
The tangent line to $\mathscr C\doteq \mathscr C(a,r)$ at $b\in \mathscr C$, I will note it $^t b\cdot \mathscr C$ for some reasons, is symply defined as $$\boxed{^t b\cdot \mathscr C\doteq \{x\in V: \langle x-b,a-b\rangle=0\}}$$It is of course a line even if it must be proved.


We could also have defined these objects in an affine plane $\mathcal P$ but it is not really necessary because we work with the vector span of an affine space(sorry for my english, we say "Enveloppe vectorielle d'un espace affine" in french), noted $$\widehat{\mathcal P}$$which is a vector space of dimension $3$, with which one does projective Geometry.
